# What is the meaning of the [JavaFlags] attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, j#

I decompiled a DLL that originally came from J#. I see the following attributes that are absent from the original code:

```
[JavaFlags(0)]
public ToolBarButton toolBarButtonProg;

[JavaFlags(8)]
public static int lastClass;
```

I see that those JavaFlags are defined in the following J# namespace.

```
namespace com.ms.vjsharp.cor
{
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = false)]
  public class JavaFlags : Attribute
  {
    public int attr;

    public JavaFlags(int attr)
    {
      this.attr = attr;
    }
  }
}
```

But what is the purpose of these attributes?

Comment: This isn't built in, as far as I know. Did you try to decompile and see where `JavaFlagsAttribute` is defined.

Comment: @Oded pleace see my edit.

Comment: If you find _where_ this is reflected on (what reflection code looks for this attribute), you will be able to find what it means. There is no way to tell from the code.

Comment: @Oded, the pasted code of this Attribute came from the compiled dll.

Comment: I appreciate that, but attributes are just meta data to be used in reflection. If you can find what reflected over the code looking for this attribute you will be able to see what the attribute values are used for - there is no way to tell outside of that.

Comment: http://www.developmentnow.com/g/47_2004_3_0_0_250312/Why-does-C-see-protected-java-members-as-public.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This attribute is likely added by the J# compiler to represent Java constructs which are not directly represented in the CLR. For example, there is no visibility modifier in the CLR which exactly mirrors the `protected` modifier in Java, so the compiler produces a method that is `public` in the CLR along with a `[JavaFlags(4)]` attribute so the J# compiler knows to treat the method as `protected` when compiling other Java code.